# Creating a display using tkinter and labels - how to run two things at the same time

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, multiprocessing, label, display

I am creating a display using a tkinter label. I have lists of variables established for every line of "pixels", aka:

```
Line1 = []

Line2 = []
```

So that the number of lines is also the height of the display. The width of the display is the number of characters in each line, which I have added like this:

```
A = range(1, 311)

for b in A:
    i = " "
    Line1.append(i)
    Line2.append(i)
```

I then transform the empty spaces into empty spaces which will actually print like empty spaces (I do not really understand this part since I got it from a question that I asked here, but it works, and I am happy it does) ...

```
LLine1 = ''.join(map(str, Line1))

LLine2 = ''.join(map(str, P2))
```

And finally, I "display" the display using a label:

```
Display = tkinter.Label(window, text = (LLine1, "\n", LLine2)
```

Up to here, every think should work properly. Now here comes the problem. In order for the display to show images, I need my program to change the variables and at the same time configure the label - possibly using... eeh... queues(?)... multi-threading(??)... multi-processing(???)? Basically, I need something like this:

```
threads.append(threading.Thread(target = Start_tkinter))
threads.append(threading.Thread(target = Start_running))
map(lambda x: x.start(), threads)
```

Where "Start_tkinter" configures the label sixty times per second using this (which will be in a loop):

```
window.mainloop() //this part will obviously not be a part of the loop
LLine1 = ''.join(map(str, Line1))  //But all this will be in the loop
LLine2 = ''.join(map(str, Line2))
Display.config(text = (PP1, PP2))
Display.after(16, count)
```

And "Start_running" changes the variables (which will also be in a loop). However, this does not work. So... what is the problem? I know that I have almost no experience, so and tips on any part of this programs are VERY appreciated :)

Comment: This is very interesting. I can't think of a way to do this off the top of my head, but perhaps tkinter isn't the right library for this? Have you considered using a library like Pygame? tkinter doesn't typically play very nice with multiprocessing applications (It's possible just not *easy*).

Answer (score 0):

About your question with changing variables i may choose tkinter StringVar

```
import tkinter as Tk
root=Tk.Tk()
Var=Tk.StringVar()
Var.set("Some string")
print(Var.get())
Label=Tk.Label(root, text=Var.get())
Label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

you can insert text by command set()

```
Var.set("Some string")
```

and insert to tkinter lable by get()

```
Label=Tk.Label(root, text=Var.get())
Label.pack()
```

and the label may change too.

I think this is the one of best solutions because you don´t need to change Labels, but only variables, which is much faster.On the other hand you need  same number of variables as your resolution.